# Dynamic Template in SendGrid: check a string

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm creating a dynamic template in SendGrid. I want to change the color of a field based on a field in my case *Success*.

For example, this is my `json`.

```
{
    "Environment": "[DEV] ",
    "RunAtTime": "09/06/2020 11:29:02 +01:00",
    "Status": "Success",
    "OrganisationId": "6",
    "OrganisationName": "Test",
    "InvoiceId": "2",
    "InvoiceRef": "Acme Ltd., A1 Taxis",
    "Amount": "50.00"
}
```

Following the [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#basic-if-else-else-if), I tried to do something like

```
{{#if this.Status = 'Success'}}
#00b300
{{else}}
#ff0000
{{/if}}
```

I found example only for boolean field.

My goal is to change the text color based on a field. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Sendgrid doesn't allow to check strings like this
Please modify code as below

```
{{#equals this.Status "Success"}}
```

Reference link for other conditions statements:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#conditional-statements